# How initial Message property in Exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I created the Exception instance, Exception ctor and Init method were called :
[image]

```cs
  [Fact]
  public void FinallyChecker()
  {
     var t = new Exception();
     _testOutputHelper.WriteLine(t.Message); // Выдано исключение типа "System.Exception".
  }
```

I don't initial _message field, how was field initialled?

Comment: Please, don't post code as images. Also, why do you need to use the custom `Exception` class instead of default one?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,138

Comment: @HansPassant, you gave answer